# Rails do not save form to the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a association between Printlist and Product, Template and Paper Type, but I'm getting an error. When I submit the new form, it redirects to the index route, but ramains at the same new page and do not save the info to the DB.

**Controller:**

```
class PrintlistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_printlist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @printlists = Printlist.all

    @preco = calcular_preco(Printlist.count(:id),Printlist.count(:id),Printlist.count(:id),Printlist.count(:id),Printlist.count(:id),Printlist.count(:id),Printlist.count(:id))
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @printlist = Printlist.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    #binding.pry
    #product = Product.where('codref': product_params['codref'])
    #template = Poster.find(layout_params['id'])
    #size = Cartaze.find(cartaz_params['id'])

    #if product.nil?
    # product = Product.new
    # product.codref = product_params['codref']
    # product.title = product_params['title']
    # product.tipo = product_params['tipo']
    # product.size = product_params['size']
    # product.save  
    #end
    @printlist = Printlist.new(printlist_params)
    #@printlist.product = product
    #@printlist.template = template
    #@printlist.size = size

    respond_to do |format|
      if @printlist.save
        format.html { redirect_to printlists_path , notice: 'Impression was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @printlist }
      else
        format.html{ render :new }
        format.json{ render json: @printlistst.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @printlist.update(printlist_params)
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @printlist }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @printlist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @printlist = Printlist.find(params[:id])
    @printlist.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(Printlists_path) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_printlist
      @printlist = Printlist.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def printlist_params
      params.require(:printlist).permit(:product_id, :poster_id, :cartaze_id)
    end

    def calcular_preco(na0, na1, na2, na3, na4, na5, na6)
    #formulando preco
    #precos = {a0: 1, a1: 2, a2: 3, a3: 4, a4: 5, a5: 6, a6: 7}
    @cartaz = Cartaze.all
    pr = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(@cartaz.map{ |c| [c.size.to_s,c.price.to_f] }.to_h)
    #precos = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({a0: 1, a1: 2, a2: 3, a3: 4, a4: 5, a5: 6, a6: 7})
    @preco_total = (na0 * pr[:A0]) + (na1 * pr[:A1]) + (na2 * pr[:A2]) + (na3 * pr[:A3]) + (na4 * pr[:A4]) + (na5 * pr[:A5]) + (na6 * pr[:A6])
  end
  #def product_params
  #params.require(:product_id).permit(:product_id)
  #end
  #def poster_params
  # params.require(:poster).permit(:id)
  #end
  #def cartaze_params
  # params.require(:cartaze).permit(:id, :size)
  #end
end
```

**new.html.erb.rb form:**

```
<%= render "/partials/sidebar" %>
<div class="conteudo-dash">
    <div class="linha-dash">
        <div class="panel panel-defaul col-md-6">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h2>Cadastro de Cartaz</h2>
                <%= form_for(@printlist, url: printlists_path) do |f|%>

                <%= f.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :title,{}, {class: "form-control col-md-3"}) %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:poster_id, Poster.all, :id, :name,{},{class: "form-control"}) %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:cartaze_id, Cartaze.all, :id, :size, {},{class: "form-control"}) %><br>
                <%= f.submit "Salvar Produto", class: "btn btn-success" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**printlist.rb model:**

```
class Printlist < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :posters
  belongs_to :cartazes
  belongs_to :products
end
```

**schema.rb:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170523202905) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "cartazes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "product"
    t.decimal  "price",      precision: 7, scale: 2
    t.string   "tipo"
    t.string   "size"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
  end

  create_table "dashboards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "products_id"
    t.integer  "posters_id"
    t.integer  "cartazes_id"
    t.index ["cartazes_id"], name: "index_dashboards_on_cartazes_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["posters_id"], name: "index_dashboards_on_posters_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["products_id"], name: "index_dashboards_on_products_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "dashboards_posters", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "dashboard_id", null: false
    t.integer "poster_id",    null: false
    t.index ["dashboard_id", "poster_id"], name: "index_dashboards_posters_on_dashboard_id_and_poster_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "posters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "printlists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "poster_id"
    t.integer  "cartaze_id"
    t.index ["cartaze_id"], name: "index_printlists_on_cartaze_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["poster_id"], name: "index_printlists_on_poster_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_printlists_on_product_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.string   "tipo"
    t.string   "size"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.decimal  "preco_promo", precision: 7, scale: 2
    t.string   "codref"
  end

  create_table "servicos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "dashboards", "cartazes", column: "cartazes_id"
  add_foreign_key "dashboards", "posters", column: "posters_id"
  add_foreign_key "dashboards", "products", column: "products_id"
end
```

**EDIT**

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'notification/create'

  resources :products
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
 # user_root_path 'dashboard#index' # DEPOIS DO CLIENTE ESTAR LOGADO redireciona pra dashboard
 post 'pgtcheckout/create'
 post 'notification', to: 'notification#create'
 resources :users
 get 'pgtcheckout' => 'pgtcheckout#index'
 get 'pgtcheckout/new' => 'pgtcheckout#new'
 resources :dashboards
 resources :product
 resources :posters
 resources :printlists
```

**Console Output**

```
Started POST "/printlists" for ::1 at 2017-05-29 13:53:04 -0300
Processing by PrintlistsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"KrKq5k71/exf2nnw56F43IbbZz7CRdjnsvTSulSNAM9Uj8lPB8tnQ9BfDifeXlMLVTNqIs6/T1dSeIS5zeph
sQ==", "printlist"=>{"product_id"=>"7", "poster_id"=>"4", "cartaze_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Salvar Produto"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1
]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering printlists/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered partials/_sidebar.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Poster Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "posters".* FROM "posters"
  Cartaze Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "cartazes".* FROM "cartazes"
  Rendered printlists/new.html.erb within layouts/application (52.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1117ms (Views: 1106.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

**Debug Output:**

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: KrKq5k71/exf2nnw56F43IbbZz7CRdjnsvTSulSNAM9Uj8lPB8tnQ9BfDifeXlMLVTNqIs6/T1dSeIS5zephsQ==
  printlist: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
    parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      product_id: '1'
      poster_id: '3'
      cartaze_id: '3'
    permitted: false
  commit: Salvar Produto
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: Actually I have no errors, When I submit it just redirects me to the index route, but it remains at "new page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `Printlist` object is failing a validation when executing `@printlist.save` on `create` action; that's why you get a `(0.0ms)  ROLLBACK` in your logs.

So, `@printlist.save` returns false and executes `format.html { render :new }`; as instructed in `create` action:

```
if @printlist.save
  format.html { redirect_to printlists_path , notice: 'Impression was successfully created.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @printlist }
else
  format.html{ render :new }
  format.json{ render json: @printlistst.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

To spot the error, use `save!` instad of `save` (this is only temporary), that will raise an exception describing why the object is not valid, and thus not saving.

With `save!` in place, now you will get an exception (instead of a ROLLBACK) in your logs with the error message.

Once you spot why your validation fails, you can fix it; and don't forget to change back `save!` to `save`.

Comment: I had a form error at the index.html page and this helped to show the error